# View Cell error in Xamarin.Forms Windows Phone

Tags: listview, xamarin, windows-phone, xamarin.forms

My app have two list view which loads from an url. First is the main category and the second is sub-category. While clicking on the first item in main category list it will populate the sub category list corresponding to the selected main value.
The problem is I can't navigate back to my main category again in WP.

The Viewcell and Imagecell works fine in Android.

If I use an ImageCell instead of Viewcell i can successfully navigate to main category.

What should be the reason ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've had a lot of `ViewCell` rendering problems on WP8.1. Maybe your list is going back, but ViewCell is not displaying it. If thats the case, try rotating your phone to see if its rendering problem, the main category list might appear. It wont help you, but might narrow the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've always had too many rendering with `ViewCell` on WP8.1.

I wanted to do the same thing you did, but read at too many places that putting a scrollable component inside another scrollable component never gives you desired result.

Instead, I choose to use a single ListView. When the main category is tapped, load the list view with Sub categories.
To go back you can have a sub category ". . ."

Add the GoBack subcategory to the list before you add other subcategories.[image]